# Занятие и освобождение потоков в QThreadPool

Tags: qt, qt5

Из справки Qt совершенно неочевидно, в каких ситуациях может потребоваться функционал методов `QThreadPool::reserveThread()` и `QThreadPool::releaseThread()`. Понятно, что если мы какой-либо поток резервируем, то не даём пулу его использовать. Но точно также можно просто уменьшить количество доступных пулу потоков через использование метода `setMaxThreadCount()`. И там, и там резервирование потоков производится безадресно, то есть без указания конкретного из них. Тогда в каких случаях может быть полезно именно `reserve/release`?

---

В процессе использования этого функционала был [обнаружен баг](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-20251). @ixSci [локализовал](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30801673#30801673) проблему. Помочь может соответствующее описанию исправление и пересборка Qt. Ну или ждать, пока не исправят официально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setMaxThreadCount задает максимальное кол-во потоков в пуле. Но их по факту может быть и меньше. Все задачи, которые помещаются в пул, распределяются между ними. reserveThread резервирует один тред из этого списка для пользовательских задач. Но если кол-во тредов в пуле уже  равно максимуму, то reserveThread добавит ещё один сверху и activeThreadCount будет больше maxThreadCount.

**UPD:**

Одно из возможных применений reserveThread/releaseThread следующее. Допустим, в тредпул помещена задача, которая ждет чего то по сети. Если все задачи будут висеть и ждать, то пул будет работать не очень эффективно. Вызывая для для пула reserveThread, мы позволяем тредпулу создать ещё один тред при необходимости. Когда ожидание завершиться и тред в пуле перейдет к активнной работе, нужно вызвать releaseThread.

Comment: То есть наоборот? Reserve - это увеличение потоков в пуле? Интересно. Но почему тогда просто не увеличить кол-во потоков через `setMaxThreadCount()`? Не очень понятно, в чём разница. Только в том, что счётчик `activeThreadCount` будет больше `maxThreadCount`?

Comment: если Вы увеличиваете кол-во потоков через setMaxThreadCount, то они все "равноправны" и пул будет их использовать. И Ваша важная задача может быть не выолнена вовремя.

Comment: Ах, вот оно что. С примером стало яснее. Спасибо.