# Нужно ли удалять указатель на QRunnable

Tags: c++, qt5, память

Использую так называемый `QThreadPool` и закидываю в него указатель на `QRunnable`. Такой код:

```
void QThreadPoolServer::incomingConnection(qintptr handle)
{
    QSocketRunnable *runnable = new QSocketRunnable(handle);

    this->thread_pool->start(runnable);
}
```

Нужно ли "ручками" очищать `QRunnable`? Или метод `QThreadPool::start()` сам всё сделает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [справке](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrunnable.html#autoDelete):

> If auto-deletion is enabled, `QThreadPool` will automatically delete
>   this runnable after calling `run();` otherwise, ownership remains with
>   the application programmer.

Что в переводе:

> Если автоудаление включено (по умолчанию это именно так), то пул
>   потоков самостоятельно уничтожит объект `QRunnable` после выхода
>   контекста выполнения из метода `QRunnable::run()`. В обратном случае
>   ответственность за удаление объекта лежит на вызывающей стороне (на
>   разработчике приложения).

---

**Предупреждение**

Следует быть [осторожным](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/525738/) при использовании автоматического удаления объектов `QRunnable` и связки `QThreadPool::releaseThread()` / `QThreadPool::reserveThread()`. В отдельных случаях возможны утечки памяти.